# Rails lists have .first and .second – is there a .hundredth or .sixty_nineth ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enumerable

Is there a class or other extension for Rails that allows more than the first few elements in a series (and the last)?  These work:

```
[2,45,2,14,53,23,634,346,34,46,643,634,346,34,34].fifth
# -> 53
[2,45,2,14,53,23,634,346,34,46,643,634,346,34,34].last
# -> 34
```

so where is?

```
list.sixth
list.hundredth
```

Comment: Is it possible to access this on a collection of objects, like `Client.where( active: true ).second`?

Comment: @JoshPinter it should be, given that [ActiveRecord collections are naturally Array class, but mimic being something else](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065425/why-are-rails-model-association-results-not-naturally-activerecordrelations).  The link here is to a discussion I had on the same issue.

Comment: Yup, after giving it a quick try, this does indeed work. What **doesn't** work is `Client.second` or `Client.third`. Acting directly on the Class, only `Client.first` and `Client.last` work. Cheers.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

There was a time when Rails added these, but there was a lot of [controversy](http://www.kerrybuckley.org/2008/11/24/my-very-small-part-in-the-arrayforty_two-controversy/) so most were removed. The only remnant of this experiment is `Array#forty_two`:

```rb
(1..100).to_a.forty_two
# => 42
```

Comment: Hehe - very funny! Didn't know this.

Comment: It's actually Array#forty_second :)

Comment: @Archonic in Rails 3.2 it was still `#forty_two`

Comment: nice info! will not forget this!!

Comment: you made my day, lol - btw. in rails4 it's still Array#fourty_two

Answer (score 17):

You can just use square brackets:

```
list[6]
list[100]
```

Comment: ooh- technically list[5], list[99] (since it starts at 0)

Comment: If you need stuff from the end, you can use `list[-1]`, `list[-5]`.

Answer (score 5):

In activesupport, it does monkey patching few of these methods into Array class. If you really want more, you can take a look how to implement from activesupport:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/access.rb