# Why are Rails model association results not naturally ActiveRecord::Relations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, types, lazy-loading

I'm using Rails 3.2.0

Let's say I have:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
end

c1 = Comment.last
```

then

```
c1.articles.class
# => Array

c1.articles.where('id NOT IN (999999)').class
# => ActiveRecord::Relation
```

Why is the result of an association ***not*** a type of `ActiveRecord::Relation`?

It clearly is / was *at some point*:

```
c1.articles.to_orig
# undefined method `to_orig' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fd820cc80a8>

c1.articles.class
# => Array
```

Certain evaluations act upon an ActiveRecord::Relation object, but inspecting the class gives a different type.

---

Particularly, this breaks building lazy-loaded queries when using `merge` to concat multiple queries.

Comment: If I remember correctly the class method is lying to you - it's delegating to the target, which is an array

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, but *Rails is intentionally lying to you*. You can see this already in the method calls, and continue to see it by calling `ancestors`, which includes a slew of ActiveRecord classes:

```
c1.articles.ancestors.select { |c| c.to_s =~ /ActiveRecord/ }.size  #=> 35
```

which shows that it is very much *not* an `Array`.

This happens because what you’re getting back when calling `c1.articles` is an [`ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.9/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb)*, which [undefines `class`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.9/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb#L39) (along with many other methods). This means that `class` gets delegated via [its `method_missing`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.9/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb#L77), which [sends it to `target`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.9/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb#L89). As we can see, the class of `target` here is, in fact, `Array`:

```
c1.articles.target.class  #=> Array
```

That is where `c1.articles.class` comes from. Nevertheless, it *is* an `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

<sub>* *We can verify that it is indeed an `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy` by calling Ruby’s original `class` method on the object in question: `Object.instance_method(:class).bind(c1.articles).call`. This is a nice trick to verify that the object is not trying to pretend to be of a different class.*</sub>

Comment: @AndrewMarshall - I'd love to get your thoughts on this situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16927437/why-does-my-activerecord-scope-with-merge-return-an-array

Comment: Finding this question/answer restored my sanity after battling with a CollectionProxy in Array's clothing all week. :)

Answer (score 2):

Because when you define association, it places in your model:

```
def #{name}(*args)
  association(:#{name}).reader(*args)
end
```

**.reader()** returns AssociationProxy, which removes the **.class** method and delegates unknown methods to @target through **.method_missing**.