# Why does my ActiveRecord scope with `merge` return an array?

Tags: ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a scope on my `Contract` model that uses `merge` and returns an array, not an `ActiveRecord::Relation` as I would like.

Yes, I've seen it said that ["It is an ActiveRecord::Relation, but Rails is intentionally lying to you"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14073828/4376). But in this case:

- The scope uses `merge`
- it only works if it's the last scope in the chain
- The object it returns says it's of class `Array`
- The object it returns has nothing about `ActiveRecord` in its ancestors
- Calling `ActiveRecord::Relation` methods like `scoped` on the return value raises raises `NoMethodError: undefined method 'scoped' for []:Array`.

The scope is on `Contract` and looks something like

```
scope :hourly, scoped.merge(Division.find_by_name!('Hourly').contracts)
```

Why is this returning an array? Can I get it to return an `ActiveRecord::Relation`?

Comment: It is my experience that a merge in a scope always returns out. The same way as calling `scoped.to_a` does. Could you not create a new scope as a `lambda` with another scope calling `scoped.hourly.contracts`?

Comment: What happens if you do `scope :hourly, -> { merge(Division.find_by_name!('Hourly').contracts) }`? Does that work?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall - nope, I still get back an array.

Comment: So far I can only get the scope to work by using `joins("INNER JOIN...")`

Comment: @CharlesJHardy - I don't quite follow what you're suggesting. Can you give a code sample in an answer?

Comment: What is `Division.find_by_name!('Hourly').contracts`? An Array or Relation?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall - it returns an array! Was I just wrong in thinking a `has_many` would return a relation? Would something like `post.comments` *ever* be a relation? (Can't believe I'm confused about something so basic.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ref comments above. I gave this a go with a dummy relationship which I expect you have with Division and Contract.

```
# app/models/contract.rb

scope :hourly,
  select: 'distinct contracts.*',
  joins: :divisions,
  conditions: {
    "divisions.name" => 'Hourly'
  },
  order: :id

contracts = Contracts.hourly
# => [#<Contract id: 1>, #<Contract id: 2>]

contracts.class
# => #<ActiveRecord::Relation>

contracts.scoped.class
# => #<ActiveRecord::Relation>

contracts.arel
# => #<Arel::SelectManager:0x007fab629f7e90>

contracts.to_a
# => [#<Contract id: 1>, #<Contract id: 2>]

contracts.to_sql
# => SELECT distinct contracts.* FROM `contracts` INNER JOIN `divisions` ON `divisions`.`contract_id` = `contracts`.`id` WHERE `divisions`.`name` = 'Hourly' ORDER BY id
```

Let me know if this is what you were looking for...

Comment: This works! The query it produces is the same as what I had fallen back to doing with `.joins("INNER JOIN...")`. I can't seem to find documentation on defining scopes this way, though. Can you point to any?

Comment: Good to hear :) To be honest I mainly just read the rails source. [Here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb) is the most helpful part but looking at all the Arel relation stuff and watching some of Aaron Patterson talks helped.